# What does the word 「こいや」 mean?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language, imperatives

The full sentence is 「ちょっと こいや」.

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it in his answer, I am going to mention it here.  It is the tough guy's imperative.  Everyone says "Come here." in English, but only a limited number of people would say 「ちょっとこいや。」 in Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a word on its own, but a combination of 来い (imperative "come") and や (see #3 in [this dictionary entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/220994/m0u/%E3%82%84/)).

As l'électeur pointed out in the comments, it can be understood as a "tough guy's imperative."

Answer (score 1):

This means *come here* and it is quite casual.

Answer (score 1):

As l'électeur said, it definitely shows tough guy's commanding nature. For example consider the following statement:

> そんなの忘れてちょっくら晩飯でも食いにこいや。
>
> Forget your troubles for a while and come and
>   have dinner with us.

In the statement above

> ちょっくら means a little
>
> 晩飯 or ばんめし means dinner
>
> 食い or くい means eating

As you can understand from the context, the speaker's statement has somewhat demanding/commanding nuance attached to it. I think if you understand the nuance, you will understand how and when to use it.