# What grammatical function is や performing here?

Tags: grammar, song-lyrics, particle-や

> それで何だっけ?
>   昨日の夜の話
>   全然覚えてない**や**
>   「電話が鳴って君からだってわかったら
>   急に変な気分になったんだ。」

This is an excerpt of lyrics from Indigo la End's song [彼女の相談](http://www.littleoslo.com/lyj/home/indigo-la-end-%E5%BD%BC%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%B8%E8%AB%87/). I can't figure out what function the や in line 3 performs.

Does anyone have any input?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

や at the end of a sentence has various meanings, but it's roughly categorized into two.

1. Kansai colloquial copula や (used in place of だ)
2. True sentence-end/interjectory particle や

Perhaps you'll see Kansai-ben's や more often, and it's discussed in many existing questions here:

- [I don't understand what やな means at the end of a sentence...?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18385/5010)
- [The meaning of んや](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/62558/5010)

But since や in your example comes right after ない, it's a sentence-end particle. (You cannot say ないだ, right?) It has several functions.

1. [after an i-adjective] Exclamation ("Oh", "Wow", sounds childish)

   > すごいや！ Wow, it's great!
   > ひどいや！ You're so cruel!
2. [after an imperative verb] Persuasion, urging ("Come on", "You", sounds masculine and rough) See: [What does the word 「こいや」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23352/5010) and [What does the sentence ending particle や mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15288/5010)

   > 飲めや。 Drink it.
   > 死ねや！ You, die!
3. [after an animate noun] Vocative ("Hey", "O", sounds old) See: [What does や after someone's name mean exactly?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61674/5010)

   > シンデレラや、舞踏会に行きたいのかい？ Cinderella, do you want to go to the ball?
4. [usually after いい or ない] Indifference, giving up, reluctant acceptance ("Oh well", "Meh") See: [Meaning of や in 「もうどうだっていいや」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34224/5010) and [Help understanding いいやって and いやだなって](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29068/5010)

   > それでいいや。 Well, that's okay (if not ideal).
   > どうでもいいや。 Whatever. / Let it go. / I don't care.
   > もう知らないや。 I don't care about it anymore.
   > うーん、わかんないや。 Hmm, I don't know. / I give up.
5. [archaic; after a noun or an old adjective] Deep emotion, exclamation ("O", "Oh", "!", "...", poetic and old, typically seen in haiku) See: [What is the function of 「や」 in this sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84063/5010) and [Translation of うらめしや](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54065/5010)

   > 古池や蛙飛び込む水の音 (famous haiku)

In your case, や is used in the fourth sense. This や expresses the speaker is not particularly serious about 覚えていない(こと). In the lyrics, the woman is serious, but the guy doesn't even remember what they talked about yesterday.