# What is the function of 「や」 in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, literature, poetry, particle-や

> 古池や 蛙飛び込む 水の音

This is a haiku by Matsuo Bashō. Is the や particle doing what it normally does, listing items?

Comment: Not sure if you are aware this is a famous haiku. I think that piece of information is indispensable to your question.

Answer (score 6):

The や indicates 詠嘆・感動 (exclamation/admiration). It's categorized as a 間投助詞 (interjectory particle) in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%84-647430):

> や 四 間助
> ３ 詠嘆・感動の意を表す。
> 「いで、あな幼な**や**」〈源・若紫〉
> 「夏草**や**つはものどもが夢の跡／芭蕉」〈奥の細道〉

And 明鏡国語辞典 categorizes it as a 終助詞 (final particle):

> や (三)〘終助〙
> ❸ 詠嘆を表す。「これはすごい**や**」「ああ、恐ろし**や**、恐ろし**や**」「高く泳ぐ**や**鯉のぼり〈鯉のぼり〉」◇俳句の切れ字もこれ。「古池**や**[蛙]{かはづ}飛び込む水の音〈芭蕉〉」

Answer (score 5):

This や is a literary particle used to add emotion or exclamation. It's common in in haiku and waka. It works like `O` as in "O the ancient pond", or `...` as in "The ancient pond...". Note that や has several roles. See [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84) (the 4th definition) and the following question:

- [What grammatical function is や performing here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66290/5010)

Comment: あっ You beat me to it! しまったまたやっちゃたぁ。。ww

Comment: @Chocolate またというか、結構久しぶりのような…ｗ